# Infinispan.war missing in 5.3.0.Final version

Tags: java, caching, jboss, memcached, infinispan

Hi I am trying to use infinispan as a remote caching solution and when following through the guide i see the following:

> ```
> > This server provides easy to use RESTful HTTP access to the Infinispan
> > data grid, build on JAX_RS. This application is delivered (currently)
> > as a WAR file, which you can deploy to a servlet container (as many
> > instances as you need).
> ```

I could not find the WAR in the 5.3.0.Final.

But i see that Infispan Server installation can serve as a Remote Data Grid, so is the REST interface included in the server installation with the latest release?

If yes

What server is it running on ?

Do we need licence to run the Server on enterprise level?

What is the good way to deploy it in any other Application Server?

Any help will be highly appreciated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But i see that Infinispan Server installation can serve as a Remote Data Grid, so is the REST interface included in the server installation with the latest release?

We will be talking about this: https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan-server Answer is, I'd say, yes. When you will use Infinispan Server, you will have possibility of accessing Infinispan cache via REST endpoint. (see readme + see endpoint subsystem in, for example, standalone.xml configuration file)  After start of this standalone server you can connect to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/ (REST server)` and start using it according to the rules described in the documentation.

> What server is it running on ?

The whole Infinispan server is very based on JBoss AS. Imagine "big" JBoss AS minus all unnecessary systems, subsystems and functionality. This "little boy" is Infinispan Server which, for example, doesn't support deploying applications etc.

> Do we need licence to run the Server on enterprise level?

No. This is open source project. If you still looking for "officially" supported version, I'd suggest you to check Red Hat's JBoss Data Grid solution, which is productized and supported Infinispan + Infinispan Server. See http://www.redhat.com/products/jbossenterprisemiddleware/data-grid/

> What is the good way to deploy it in any other Application Server?

There is no such a way. As I mentioner earlier, Infinispan Server itself is standalone server which already contains everything you need for caching and running cluster of virtually 128 (or even more) nodes.

> Any help will be highly appreciated?

Maybe. I can't answer this question properly :(

Comment: Hi Tsykora thanks for the detailed explanation. I have one more question .. i downloaded 6.0.0.CR1 server installation and launched 2  instances using cluster.bat on my machine with all default configuration and i can see the cluster formed but when i launch another instance on a different machine in the same network it does not add to the cluster . is there anything i need to change in the cluster.xml to allow that ?